# C# View page URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a controller, called `ClientController.cs` and VS automatically created the necessary `View` files in `/Views/Client`. But I wanted to get these pages in a different URL... So, it is /Client but I need it at /admin/client.

What should I change?

Thank you!

Comment: And what is the start? What exact problem do you have? What does not let you go on?

Comment: URLs are determined by the routing engine and have nothing to do with the location of the views folder.  The views folder, by default, needs to match the name of the controller.

Comment: Not really sure why this question is closed. It's pretty clear if you know anything about asp.net MVC. I was literally just about to post an answer when it was closed... which is annoying

Comment: agree with musefan, no disrespect to dominic but i find that comment more confusing than the question and yet its been marked up

Comment: @JaceRhea Thanks! I've created a route rule for this, so the redirection is working now. But how can I disable the access for the default route (/Client)?

Comment: @user3227568  I'm not sure exactly, but it would be something like this...  routes.IgnoreRoute("/Client");   If you are creating a lot of admin routes you may want to look into the the concept of "Areas".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what your functionality will be in the long run, but here are a few options that allow you to get the URL format you want:

1. Perhaps you want a controller called "Admin" and an action called "Client". This would give you a path of `/Admin/Client` by default
2. Alternatively, you can [change your route maps](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs). For example, the following with route `/Admin/Client` to the Index of your Client controller:

   `routes.MapRoute(
       "Default",  // Route name
       "Admin/Client/{action}",  // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Client", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
   );`
3. Or maybe even go a far as [using "Areas"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), depending on what you need. Have a Google of that if you're interested in learning more

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be admin/client, then using the default routing you should create an Admin Controller with an ActionResult method called Client. Your views folder should have an admin folder with your client view inside.

I haven't done a lot of MVC but i believe this is what you do.

Comment: The /Views/Client is a folder now and it has few cshtml file (create, edit, delete, etc.), so if I create an Admin controller and a Client action it might be not the best option... but I'm not sure... just started to learn the C# MVC... :) Sorry if I have git dumb questions... :/ The route solution is sound better for me. Am I wrong?

Comment: The route option has been suggested by someone far more clever than I. My suggestion is working with the defaulting routing, but it sounds like you want something more than that. On that basis the routing sounds pretty good to me.